# typescript compiler bug? knockout.validation.d.ts doesn't compile anymore

Tags: typescript

I just updated Typescript from v2.3 to v2.4, and now it is giving me an error on the knockout.validation.d.ts lines:

```
interface KnockoutSubscribableFunctions<T> {
    isValid: KnockoutComputed<boolean>;
    isValidating: KnockoutObservable<boolean>;
    rules: KnockoutObservableArray<KnockoutValidationRule>;
    isModified: KnockoutObservable<boolean>;
    error: KnockoutComputed<string>;
    setError(error: string): void;
    clearError(): void;
}
```

Here knockout.validation is trying to indicate that KnockoutSubscribableFunctions now has extra members. Here is the definition of this interface in knockout.d.ts:

```
interface KnockoutSubscribableFunctions<T> {
    [key: string]: KnockoutBindingHandler;

    notifySubscribers(valueToWrite?: T, event?: string): void;
}
```

the compiler now complains that:

> Property 'isValid' of type 'KnockoutComputed' is not assignable to string index type 'KnockoutBindingHandler'.

I don't understand why it doesn't see these new values as new properties in the interface? why is it trying to say that they have to map onto the index signatures? The [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) seem to indicate that you can have the index signature and other properties in the same interface.

I took the initial definition of the interface into the playground and it even complained that notifySubscribers isn't assignable to a KnockoutBindingHandler.

With the new compiler how would you get this code to compile?

For now there I'm using a brute force method to get this to compile, in which I am changing the knockout.d.ts definition to be as follows:

```
interface KnockoutSubscribableFunctions<T> {
    [key: string]: any;//KnockoutBindingHandler;

    notifySubscribers(valueToWrite?: T, event?: string): void;
}
```

Comment: You're getting an error on the original interface alone? Or is there more to the code? I don't see why you'd get an error unless you were trying to assign something to something of type `KnockoutSubscribableFunctions`.

Comment: The complier is flagging the error on the line in knockout.d.ts, even though it is complaining about the members defined in knockout.validation.d.ts. This appears to have nothing to do with my code. I will see about creating a brand new project that only includes these two .d.ts files. But my impression is that just having these two files together with nothing else will give me the error.

Comment: Oh and if it wasn't clear, this compiled just fine in the 2.3 version of the compiler. I just upgraded to 2.4.1 and got this error compiling the same project without making any changes to the project.

Answer (score 25):

The problem exists because of differences in types of the:

```
[key: string]: KnockoutBindingHandler;
```

And other params:

```
isValid: KnockoutComputed<boolean>;
isValidating: KnockoutObservable<boolean>;
rules: KnockoutObservableArray<KnockoutValidationRule>;
isModified: KnockoutObservable<boolean>;
error: KnockoutComputed<string>;
setError(error: string): void;
clearError(): void;
```

The error you got basically says: the KnockoutComputed type can't be assigned to the KnockoutBindingHandler type.

Probably this compile-time checking are improved in TS 2.4, that's why you hadn't had this problem previously.

Your solution works:

```
[key: string]: any;//KnockoutBindingHandler;
```

And if you can change this code you may try another a little bit "prettier" solution:

```
[key: string]: any | KnockoutBindingHandler;
```

Which might provide you some additional autocomplete help.

Comment: You are correct. I was looking at this page: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html under the section of Excess Property Checks as an example where the compiler allows other properties as well as specific properties, but in the example, they too used : any. Its a pity really. The way the knockout.d.ts is currently defined looks like it should work and work well. There are some specific members and then there is the possibility of other members of a KnockoutBindingHandler type.

Comment: I have the same problem with knockout.d.ts since upgrading from TS 2.1 to TS 2.5. Like Mark says, TypeScript 2.4 introduces additional type checks that exposes some potential "type problems" with the current knockout.d.ts (in my case knockout.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped v1.1.6). One solution to this problem seems to be to set skipLibCheck to true, eg in tsconfig.json

Comment: Ps. If you are building in Visual Studio, skipLibCheck can be configured in two ways: you can either add a tsconfig.json and specify "skipLibCheck": true under compilerOptions OR add an msbuild parameter in your .csproj-file:     
    <TypeScriptSkipLibCheck>True</TypeScriptSkipLibCheck>

Comment: I had a similar issue (knockout.d.ts) when building a project that used TypeScript 2.2 in Visual Studio 2017. Installing [TypeScript SDK for Visual Studio 2017 v2.3.3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55258) and updating the project to use TypeScript 2.3 "resolved" the issue. It doesn't fix any underlying issue, but the build is now successful.